# Expected value of $\sigma$ in GARCH model

Tags: time-series, expected-value, garch

In a standard GARCH(1,1) process defined as:
$$\varepsilon_t=\sigma_t z_t \\ 
\text{ where } z_t \sim \text{ iid } N(0,1) \\
\text{ and } \sigma_t^2 =\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \varepsilon^2_{t-1} + \alpha_2 \sigma_{t-1}^2 $$

It is simple to show that  $ E[\sigma_t^2]=\frac{\alpha_0}{1 - \alpha_1 - \alpha_2} $. But what I am trying to derive is:
$$ E[\sigma_t] = ? $$
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We can write $var(\sigma_t) = E[\sigma_t^2] - E[\sigma_t]^2 $. As we know $E[\sigma_t^2]$, finding $var(\sigma_t)$ would be enough to derive $E[\sigma_t]$. But it doesn't look easier.